# Condition row total as a column in another table using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Firstly, I apologize for the terrible wording, but I'm not sure how to describe what I'm doing...

I have a table of computer types (id, type, name), called com_types

```
id    |    type    | name    
 1    |     1      | Dell
 2    |     4      | HP
```

In a second table, I have each individual computer, with a column 'type_id' to denote what type of computer it is, called com_assets

```
id    |    type_id    |  is_assigned
 1    |       4       |  0
 2    |       1       |  1
```

I'd like to create a view that shows each computer type, and how many we have on hand and in use, and a total, so the outcome would be

```
id    |    type    |    name    |    on_hand    |     in_use     |    total    |
 1    |      1     |    Dell    |       0       |       1        |      1      |
 2    |      4     |     HP     |       1       |       0        |      1      |
```

As you can see, the on_hand, in_use, and total columns are dependent on the type_id and is_assigned column in the second table.

So far I have tried this...

```
CREATE VIEW test AS

SELECT id, type, name,

( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM com_assets WHERE type_id = id AND is_assigned = '0' ) as on_hand,

( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM com_assets WHERE type_id = id AND is_assigned = '1' ) as in_use,

SUM( on_hand + in_use ) AS total

FROM com_types
```

But all this returns is one column with all correct values, except the total equals ALL of the computers in the other table. Will I need a trigger to do this instead?

Comment: Wait, so you want to show each individual record, as well as the totals for all records of a specific type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on_hand` is the count of `assigned = 0`, and `in_use` is the count of `assigned = 1`. You can count them together, without the correlated subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT
  com_types.id,
  com_types.type,
  com_types.name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN com_assets.is_assigned = 0 THEN 1 END) AS on_hand,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN com_assets.is_assigned = 1 THEN 1 END) AS in_use,
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM com_types
JOIN com_assets ON com_types.id = com_assets.id
GROUP BY
  com_types.id,
  com_types.type,
  com_types.name
```

Comment: Looks like this works at a glance. Nice one Ed. Here's a sqlfiddle where I tested it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8808d/1

Comment: Works perfectly, just tested it out. That was also very quick, Thank you so much! It looks like I need to familiarize myself with CASEs and Groups, thanks again Ed!

Comment: @dougBTV - thanks for the Fiddle! I should have done one because it shows I actually messed up: the join should be on `com_types.type = com_assets.type_id` (I had `com_types.id`). I've fixed my answer. I owe you one :)

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that too but I thought maybe I just read it wrong. Still though, 4 minute response was not what I was expecting, excellent.

Comment: Actually, it should be `com_types.id = com_assets.id`. I got confused with the duplicate `type_id` in both tables.

Comment: @zeke8402 - good; glad you caught that. I got a bit confused with the `type_id` in both tables; I'm over it now :) The query as it stands now should be good.